# How to run jqAssistant as a daemon

Tags: jqassistant

I'm running jqAssistant through command line with

```
./bin/jqassistant.sh server
```

The server starts and waits for the user to press `ENTER` to terminate.

As the process is waiting for terminal input, I cannot manage to start the server as a background process. Using `nohup` makes the server stop right after starting.

Is this behaviour intended ?
Is it possible to launch jqa as a daemon ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it's not possible to launch the server as a daemon, the primary intended use case is to give a developer a UI for exploring the graph on his machine.

It shouldn't be difficult to add a "-daemon" option to the CLI, you're invited to create a ticket on [GitHub](https://github.com/buschmais/jqassistant/issues)

Comment: Thanks for creating the issue!

Comment: Indeed a nice feature, especially in combination with a CI server. And pre-defined queries in a playbook.